# Displaying multiple records in CartoDB with common zip code

Tags: carto, zip-codes

I am uploading multiple records and want to use five digit zip code as the georeference.  I would like to display each of those records on a map. Some of the records have identical zip code fields, meaning that several records share a single zip code.  In the map view, only one of those records, among the handful that share a single zip code, appears. Is it possible to show on the map all of the records that share that single zip code?

Comment: First of all, what program are you using? What version? What format is the data in?

Comment: What software are you using to render the map?

Comment: You could just enable the zip code as field to appear in the infowindow. But not sure I'm understanding what you want to do. Could you provide a link to your map?

Answer (score 0):

The same question was answered here: [CartoDB: Displaying multiple items at same address?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135769/cartodb-displaying-multiple-items-at-same-address)

You need to aggregate the data that corresponds to a single geometry by using SQL, so that the infowindow is able to show all of them at once. If not, you'll only get the data for the geometry that is drawn in the top of the others, as they may overlap.