# Displaying multiple items at same address using Carto?

Tags: carto

I'm creating a map with specific information (name, DOB, etc) to be displayed for a street address, which is mapped to an exact lat and long. Problem I'm realizing is that for items such as apartment buildings, this isn't going to work within CartoDB using the Simple Visualization Wizard.

Any suggestions in CartoDB to display multiple fields of the same type in a click/hover window?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a query to your visualization in order to aggregate the data that is located in the exact same position.

To achieve this, you can create a new column (of type string) or use an already existing one, activate this column in your infowindows and then apply a query like:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(c.name, ' <br>' ) as new_column_aggregated, b.the_geom_webmercator, 
b.cartodb_id 
FROM tablename c, tablename b 
WHERE ST_Equals(c.the_geom, b.the_geom)
GROUP BY b.the_geom_webmercator, b.cartodb_id
```

Being name the data you want to aggregate and new_column_aggregated the column you'll activate in the infowindows.

[image: example in image]

A similar question was asked here: [How to include and format multiple rows in inforview from cartoDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132447/how-to-include-and-format-multiple-rows-in-inforview-from-cartodb)