# Carto Maps: Display different points/objects at the same location

Tags: carto, mapping

I know this question has been asked before, but I could not succeed with the help of the answers that are already out there. Can someone provide me with a detailed description (for dummies that cannot code very well ;) ) on the problem of displaying multiple objects with the same address?

I want to make a map showing the sites of the nuclear power plants and nuclear waste disposal in France using Carto. I use the column "address" for geo-localization and the column "group" to divide the data into two categories. The map so far displays only one point for each address. But often there are several power plants at one site and I would like to show that. How can I change my settings in Carto so that this works? In my data-set I have a new row for each new power plant, it is just the address that is the same.

Comment: If you know the question has been asked before, please provide a link to that question in your question.

Comment: [Displaying multiple items at same address using Carto?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/135769/41723)

Comment: In this blog post ( https://geomaticblog.net/2017/02/20/aggregating-points/ ) you can find another solution to aggregate your data and then display the content on the popup.